# How to do a JOIN on table in a HasMany relationship, if only the latest row on the joined table is searched or?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Post and PostComment model. They are in a HasMany relationship, as the picture suggests.
[ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTJ0M.png)

I need to return all posts, and, the latest comment for each post, paginated.

The problem is that I need also to do a search on the "post_comments" table. Something like "get all posts from a specific user, ...". So I decided to use the JOIN.

My problem is that with JOIN I do not receive only one entry per post, but rather as many post entries, as there are comments in the related table.

I tried to group the result by "post_id", but some critics said that this is not good. What would be the "proper approach " for this?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The proper approach since you are using laravel and not pure PHP is to use eloquent for this, so the general idea is this

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments')->with('comments')->sortByDesc('comments.created_at')->paginate(10);
```

And then when you foreach these posts in your blade or vue, you just need to do this

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
   $post->comments()->latest()->first(); // this the latest comment
}
```

Comment: One requirement that I did not mention is that I need to do "ordering" by, let's say, the "commented_at" column. Those posts that have the most recent comment, would come first, and those that have no comment, last. And also, it can be reversed. I went to JOIN, specifically because I could not get the proper pagination, with the relationships. Since they fire in a separate query, the pagination will not work.